# Add a child route to a child route

Tags: angular

The angular 2 router currently does not allow more than one level of nesting.

If you have a structure like:

```
/users/profile/detail
```

How to link to `/users/profile`, when I click button in `user` component, it should route to `profile` component?

code:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenubarComponent,
    children: [

      { path: 'page1', component: page1Component },
      { path: 'user', component: userComponent,
       children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: profileComponent },
       ]
      },
      { path: 'page2', component: page2Component },
      { path: 'page3', component: page3Component }

    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
];
```

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: What is a `non-terminal` route ? I don't really understand the question, can you provide a plunkr to show your issue ?

Comment: Does your router-outlet include another named router-outlet? I assume it is possible if the named router-outlets nested during loading. It's just an assumption, I never tried. Have you reached angular-router guys (Victor Savkin) with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `detail` child route to the `profile` route to be able to navigate to `/users/profile/detail`. Just add a 2nd child route to `profile` with a dummy component that is shown when you navigate to `/users/profile`

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenubarComponent,
    children: [

      { path: 'page1', component: page1Component },
      { path: 'user', component: userComponent,
       children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: profileComponent,
          children: [
            { path: '', component: dummyComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'detail', component: userProfileDetailComponent }
        },
       ]
      },
      { path: 'page2', component: page2Component },
      { path: 'page3', component: page3Component }

    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
];
```

Comment: "not working" isn't very helpful. Please post full and exact error messages.

Comment: Url is getting change like user/profile/detail but view of the detail component is not rendering .. only  profile component view is coming

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Does the `profileComponent` have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in its template?

Comment: no errors.. i tried to add router outlet in profile component but view of profile component is coming twice in profile component.. and also in detail component

Comment: There is nothing special about routing 2 levels deep. I don't know what might go wrong. Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular 4 template under the "new" button.

Comment: I guess you are aware that the structurd is `/**menu**/user/profile/detail` not `/user**s**/profile/detail`. How do you navigate?